# OnClickListener in ListFragment

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-listfragment

I have 6 ListFragments in my application. If you tap on a element of the ListFragment the VideoView will be started.

[image]

```
 public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
    getActivity().getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    getActivity().setContentView(R.layout.act_video_view);

    if (position < exercices.length) {
        int rawId = getResources().getIdentifier(exercices[position], "raw", getActivity().getPackageName());
        VideoView myVideoView = (VideoView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.myvideoview);
        myVideoView.setVideoPath("android.resource://" + getActivity().getPackageName() + "/" + rawId);
        myVideoView.setMediaController(new MediaController(getActivity()));
        myVideoView.requestFocus();
        myVideoView.start();
        myVideoView.setMediaController(new MediaController(this.getActivity()) {
            public boolean dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent event) {
                if (event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) getActivity().recreate();
                return super.dispatchKeyEvent(event);
            }
        });
        ActVideo.videoIsPlaying = true;
    }
}
```

Now I implemented an `imageView` in my layout xml and want to add a `OnClickListener` for it. But where I have to place it?

I tried it in `onListItemClick` after the `setContentView` but that doesn't work and the app crashes.

Do you have any suggestions for me?

Comment: how you implemented the onClick?

Comment: I first implemented it in onlistitemclick after the setContentView but that doesn't work.

Comment: please post it with your code...